# How to writte text in the middle of an image without positioning and z-index?

Tags: html, css

I am creating an email template and i need to writte text in the "middle" of an image, but some email system's doesn't allow positioning, what can i use?

My HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Black_background-5.jpg" style="width:400px; height: 350px;" />
<p style="color:blue;">SOME TEXT FOR CONTENT..</p>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/2zehs9f5/

Comment: Negative margin? Not sure how flexible that would be though.

Comment: Can't you use a div with that background image? That way you can align the text wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you @Lidaranis for the idea, i tryed this https://jsfiddle.net/9zmw2gnt/ and it worked for me in gmail, it is in the top middle of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this for email, I'd recommend adding the text to the image itself, rather than positioning it with a background-image. The reason for this is that background-image isn't very well supported (particularly in Outlook 07/10/13) and will have to fallback to a solid colour, which may ruin the entire design.

I'd also move away from `p` tags, as they can render differently in different email clients.

Here's a JSFiddle of the finished code: https://jsfiddle.net/czxrp2hf/1/

Also, this link is quite helpful for finding out what CSS is supported in which email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thank you, the solution works, before your solution i tryed this one https://jsfiddle.net/9zmw2gnt/ and it worked for me but your's is more acceptable i think..

Comment: If you have access to an email inbox tester, like Litmus, I'd recommend running an email through it before sending :) To double check it looks good in all email clients.

Answer (score 0):

All in all Natalie has right.
If you want to try something like this:

```
<td valign="middle" background="your_image.jpg" width="100%" style="background-image: url(your_image.jpg)">
Your text here
</td>
```

should work in all major mailer (web and offline); except, as far as i know, Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.

Be aware that i put both the standard definition of background image AND the inline CSS one.