# Create a line of equal square for outlook 2013 in email template (or ie 8)?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

[image]

I have created a line of square , it works in modern browser such as Gmail in google, but for outlook , it show like this:

[image]

The 4 block combine together and also the div height is not honoured, any idea or workaround?

```
<tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;padding: 10px 0px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, 'SimHei','微軟雅黑', STXihei, '華文細黑', sans-serif;">
                                            <h3 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 0px; color: #606060;">Have a Question?</h3>
                                            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700px" border="0" style="margin:auto;">
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td style="width:25%;text-align: center;"><a href="http://be-pure.com/en/" target="_blank"><img width="150" style="width:150px" src="{img_dir}en/q1.jpg" /></a></td>
                                                  <td style="width:25%;text-align: center;"><a href="http://be-pure.com/en/content/26-customer-service" target="_blank"><img width="150" style="width:150px" src="{img_dir}en/q2.jpg" /></a></td>
                                                  <td style="width:25%;text-align: center;"><a href="mailto:csr@be-pure.com"><img width="150" style="width:150px" src="{img_dir}en/q3.jpg" /></a></td>
                                                  <td style="width:25%;text-align: center; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, 'SimHei','微軟雅黑', STXihei, '華文細黑', sans-serif;">
                                                    <div style="border: 3px solid #6C6E70; height: 144px; width:144px;">
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                        <p style="color: #58595b; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px;">Useful Links</p>
                                                        <p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;"><a href="{my_account_url}" style="color: #58595b; text-decoration: none;">My Account</a></p>
                                                        <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;"><a href="http://be-pure.com/en/content/11-refund-policy" style="color: #58595b; text-decoration: none;">Return Policy</a></p>
                                                        <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 15px;"><a href="http://be-pure.com/en/content/13-frequently-asked-questions" style="color: #58595b; text-decoration: none;">FAQ</a></p>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </div>
                                                  </td>
                                               </tr>
                                           </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emails, particularly Outlook 7/10/13, it's better to define the td with a set width, rather than percentages. This then allows you to define the spaces properly (which I imagine Outlook is ignoring, and is mashing all of the td's together).

This is a great resource for how well supported some CSS is in various email clients. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ Margin is one in particular you don't want to use, as it's not supported on Outlook.com.

Also, if this is for email, I'd recommend not using p tags (as they can render differently in different email clients), you could also center the text by adding a height to the td, rather than using nbsp's - see this previous answer for how to do that: [How to writte text in the middle of an image without positioning and z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959668/how-to-writte-text-in-the-middle-of-an-image-without-positioning-and-z-index/33960059#33960059)

Comment: thanks , i will remove the nbsp , how about the div's height? if I would like to set a box , width 150px , height 150px , is it possible for outlook?

Comment: It is, but I would use a nested table and set your width and height on that :) It's the most robust way of doing it I've found, to add tables within td's.

Comment: great , how about the space between images, <td width="25%"><table width="150px"><a><img></img></a> or padding? thx

Comment: I would add another td :) Hence why I suggested using fixed px widths. For example: `<td width="100"></td><td width="15"></td><td width="100"></td><td width="15"></td><td width="100"></td>`

Comment: got it , so in my case instead of using div, use another table and set the height = 150px and the element inside vertical align need to refer the link

Answer (score 1):

Outlook doesn't support the margin property, or any of its variants: https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/

You can use padding, but not on block elements. consider changing your p tags to a table and use padding to get the look you want.

Comment: thanks for answering , the first 3 block is an image , but there is no spacing between them?

Comment: Add padding:5px to your td elements holding the img.